# Can we have environment-based endpoints with a WCF Connected Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config, service-reference

I recently migrated one of our assemblies (a referenced library) from the old CSProj format to the new CSProj format (the `Microsoft.Net.Sdk` format). This helps a lot due to the globbing rules and how it handles dependencies (reference, project reference, package reference) so well.

After the transition, there is no longer an option for "Service References", instead we have "Connected Services". I removed the old Service Reference files (code, wsdl, xsd, etc.) and created a new Connected Service.

It seems cleaner because it generates a json configuration (used for auto-generating code) and a single Reference.cs file. The auto-generated code is a bit different than the old service reference code that was generated. Firstly, all methods are async (makes sense), so I adjusted our code to account for this.

The problem I am running into is that we had originally relied on the application's Web.Config file (also Web.Dev.Config, Web.Test.Config, etc.) -- during our deploy process we rename/replace the Web.Config with the appropriate environments configuration. This worked just fine, our app added a reference to our library and the app held the config information.

With the new Connected Services auto-generated code, it is hard coding in the localhost address as the endpoint because I used that to auto-generate the code.

Basically, the old "Service Reference" generated code had the default constructor of the client pull the endpoint from the application config. The new Connected Service offers overloads, but does not by default pull the endpoint from the config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://xdev/xservice.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IXService" contract="XService.IXService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IXService" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

What do I do different to take advantage of my app config with the new WCF Connected Services auto-generated code?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Got the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54866814/1339551) answer:

There is a partial abstract method `partial void ConfigureEndpoint` in your service client to override. There you can programmatically set the endpoint via `serviceEndpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(...)`.

This URL can be stored in the `<appSettings>` of your `.config` or in the `appsettings.<Environment>.json`, depending on your platform.

**Note**, that the development endpoint from which the code was generated gets hard-coded into the sources and remains as a fallback. If for some reason your overridden method does not get called, you have a very hard to spot error. If someone has a solution for that, I'd be very interested.